# Moving down a row in a Word table containing multi-paragraph cells

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

How can I reliably move down the rows in a Word table?
Here's the structure of the table. Note that the first and second columns can both have multiple lines and paragraphs.

```
Rule ID         1

Logic           Date must be equal to or greater than 01-Jan-2012 

Discrepancy     Date is before 01-Jan-2012
message

Test case 1.1   Create form where Date is before 01-Jan-2012 
                Verify discrepancy message appears.
                Print form.

Test case 1.2   Create form where Date is equal to 01-Jan-2012.
                Verify no discrepancy message appears.
                Print form.

Test case 1.3   Create form where Date is after 01-Jan-2012.
                Verify no discrepancy message appears.
                Print form.
```

I have tried a number of methods to move down the table.

When I tried `Selection.MoveDown` with `unit:=wdLine` (below) I ran into problems when column 1 contained a word wrap.

```
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
```

When I tried `Selection.MoveDown` with `unit:=wdParagraph` (below), I ran into problems when column 2 contained multiple paragraphs.

```
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=3
```

`unit:=wdRow` does not appear to be a valid parameter for `Selection.MoveDown`.
`Selection.Cells(1).RowIndex` is a read-only parameter

Does anyone know of a simple method to move down the table one row at a time that would handle both the word wraps in column 1 and the multiple paragraphs in column 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this.  It's a generalized algorithm for looping through each row and column of all the tables in a Word document.  Modify as needed (untested code):

```
Sub ModifyAllTables()
  Dim oTbl As Table
  Dim oRow As Row
  Dim oRng As Range
  For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For Each oRow In oTbl.Rows
      ' Select the cell in column 2.
      Set oRng = oRow.Cells(2).Range
      ' and do something with it...
      'e.g. oRng.TypeText "modified"
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub NextRow()

    Dim c As Long, r As Long

    With Selection
        'ignore if not in table
        If .Information(wdWithInTable) Then

            c = .Columns(1).Index
            r = .Rows(1).Index

            If .Rows(1).Parent.Rows.Count >= r + 1 Then
                .Rows(1).Parent.Rows(r + 1).Cells(c).Range.Select
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```