# Word VBA will not accept wdCell as a valid unit to move

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to move down one cell in a word table using VBA; the problem is when I use the `unit:=wdCell` it gives me a run-time error. I can use the default `wdLine` and it works fine, but if the cell has more than one line, I end up on the second line instead of the next cell.

```
With Selection
  .MoveDown Unit:=wdCell, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
  .Expand wdCell
  .Range.Text = "Hello World"
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, you cannot use `wdCell` as a parameter to `Move*`, which does not appear to be a documented fact.

One workaround would be to jump to the end of the cell and then move one line down:

```
With Selection
    .MoveEnd wdCell
    .MoveDown wdLine, Count:=1
    .Expand wdCell
End With
```

Another workaround would be to [locate yourself in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14327376/11683) and jump to the next cell by index:

```
With Selection
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    r = .Rows(1).Index
    c = .Columns(1).Index

    If .Rows(1).Parent.Rows.Count >= r + 1 Then
        .Rows(1).Parent.Rows(r + 1).Cells(c).Range.Select
    End If
End With
```